# The group of units of $K_0$ and the Picard group of a finitely generated regular $\mathbb Z$-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, algebraic-k-theory, regular-rings

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra which is also a regular ring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_ring). Consider $K_0(A)$ which has a commutative ring structure (the multiplication being induced by tensor product).

Is it true that the group of units $K_0(A)^\times$ is finitely generated as an abelian group ? If this is not true in general, then is it atleast true that $Pic(A)$ is finitely generated as an abelian group ?

(Note that if $K_0(A)^\times$ is finitely generated then so is $Pic(A)$ because it injects into $K_0(A)^\times$ )

Comment: Hi, in your setup, Pic doesn't have to be finitely generated. Please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293668/picard-group-of-a-finite-type-mathbbz-algebra.

Comment: @MinseonShin The linked example is not a regular ring, contrary to the request of the OP. There might be a way to adapt the counterexample to this situation but there is a discrepancy here. (This is a good link and a cool proof, though, so thank you for providing the link.)

Comment: @KReiser Oops, thanks for pointing out my mistake. So it seems that $Pic(A)$ is finitely generated if $A$ is normal, as proved in Lang's "Fundamentals of Diophantine Geometry", Chapter 2, Theorem 7.6. It's a conjecture due to Bass that if $A$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra and regular, then $K_{0}(A)$ is a finitely generated abelian group. If we can also show that $K_{0}(A)$ is reduced, then we would be done by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445562/is-the-unit-group-of-any-finitely-generated-reduced-bbb-z-algebra-finitely-ge.

Comment: Oh but I guess it'd be rare for a ring to have reduced $K_{0}(A)$, in view of Lemma 3.1.4.3 (i) of Lieblich's "[Twisted sheaves and the period-index problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511244)" (but he says it's due to Gabber), which says that the kernel of the rank map $\rho : K_{0}(A) \to \mathbb{Z}$ consists of nilpotent elements.

Comment: @MinseonShin: the theorem in Lang's book that you refer to states that the Picard group of irreducible normal scheme of finite type over $\mathbb Z$ is finitely generated ... however, since I'm not assuming $A$ is integral domain, so $Spec(A)$ is not irreducible in my case ...  am I missing anything ..?

Comment: @MinseonShin: also, the object Lieblich is using in Lemma 3.1.4.3 in his paper is not quite $K_0(R)$ , which is the Grothendieck group of finitely generated projective modules, but rather it is the Grothendieck group of finitely generated projective modules of constant rank ... in general, the rank function for $K_0(R)$ is as rank$: K_0(R) \to H^0(Spec R,\mathbb Z)$ and the kernel of this map is the Nilradical of the ring $K_0(R)$ ... whereas Leiblich takes a subring of $K_0(R)$ of vevtor bundles of constant rank,so the restricting the rank function the image lands into $\mathbb Z$ .. contd.

Comment: @MinseonShin: for a reference for whatever I just said see Definition 2.3, Theorem 4.6.1 and Theorem 8.1 of Weibel's K-book

Comment: @uno Yup, you're right. However a regular Noetherian ring $A$ is a direct product of finitely many regular Noetherian domains, and so you may assume that $A$ is a domain. Then in this case finitely generated projective modules have constant rank.

Comment: @MinseonShin: ah ugh you're right ... silly me ... thanks :-)